# In Scala, multiple objects with main method can be present in a single file and run individually . What is the reason behind this?

Tags: scala, program-entry-point, scala-3

I wrote below code in scala 3 in a single file

```
@main def main11 =
  println("main11 printed something")

object Main10 extends App {
  println("Main10 Executed !!".toUpperCase())
  main11
}

object Main2  {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Main2 can run too !!".toUpperCase())
    Main10
  }
}
```

It compiles fine and I can run any of these `main11` `Main2` `Main10` in the IDE.

**What is reason for this ?**

Eg.

`main11` **output** :

```
main11 printed something
```

`Main2` **output** :

```
 MAIN2 CAN RUN TOO !!
 MAIN10 EXECUTED !!
 main11 printed something
```

Usually in other languages I see 1 main class in 1 file.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question, but it's not recommended to use `App`, since `DelayedInit` is deprecated. It's probably best to go with `@main` or an old-school main method instead.

Answer (score 3):

Scala has idiomatic concepts which require multiple classes/objects/traits within the same file such as

- companion objects
- algebraic data types

However in general it is not best practice to define arbitrary multiple classes/objects/traits within the same file unless they are tightly related. The fact that your objects happen to have each a `main` method is not relevant as it is just considered a regular method.